# I can't login to cpanel even after made database in whm

Tags: mysql, cpanel, whm

I have made a new project in whm also made a database in it and user too. but when i type www.example.com/cpanel, not opens login page of cpanel. so,where is the mistake.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I think your domain is not resolving to that cPanel server IP and due to that domiannmae/cpanel is not working.